# Contact Roles Question

Tags: opportunitycontactrole

Is there any way to pull the Contact from the Contact Roles related list into a lookup field on the record? For instance, I have a customer with hundreds of opportunities all with their primary contact in the Contact Roles related list. I'm trying to use a workflow to auto send emails from an Opportunity record, but can't reference the contact in the Contact Roles related list. I'm looking for a way to avoid the tedious activity of manually updating each record one-by-one with a lookup field to that contact. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, there isn't a way to trigger any sort of automation off of the `OpportunityContactRole` object, so you can't use something simple like a WFR or PB to accomplish this.

You could use either a trigger or a Flow to grab the `ContactId` from the `OpportunityContactRole` where `IsPrimary = True` and populate a lookup on your `Opportunity`. However, because this would be triggered off of updates to the opp itself, it's possible that this could be missing or out of date due to updates to `OpportunityContactRole` records without updating the actual `Opportunity`.